# add html <p> tag to a formatted file

Tags: html, perl, format

I have a formatted text file such as this:

```html
<P> <P>
paragraph 1 blablablabla
<P> <P>
paragraph 2 blablablabla
<P> <P>
paragraph 3 blablablabla
<P> <P>
paragraph 4 blablablabla
```

I need to transform this file to have a well formed html file like this:

```html
<p>
paragraph 1 blablablabla
</p>
<p>
paragraph 2 blablablabla
</p>
<p>
paragraph 3 blablablabla
</p>
<p>
paragraph 4 blablablabla
</p>
```

For now I use a perl script but it doesn't work:

```perl
my $p = 0;

    while(my $text = <IN>)
    {
        if($text =~ /(<P>\t<P>)/)
        {   
            $p++;
            if($p % 2 == 0){
                print "</p>"."\n";
            }
            else{
                print "<p>"."\n";

            }

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
my $p = 0;

while ( my $text = <IN> ) {
    if ( $text =~ /(<P>\s*<P>)/ ) {   
        if ( $p == 0 ) {
            $text =~ s{$&}{<P>};
        }
        else {
            $text =~ s{$&}{</P>\n<P>};
        }
        $p++;
    }
    print $text;
}
print "</P>\n";
```

Basically what it does is change any `<P> <P>` to `</P>\n<P>` except the first occurrence which in this case the replacement will be only `<P>`. Also using `\s*` instead of `\t` in the `if` condition will also handle whitespace other than `tab`.

Comment: Faster to simply ignore/skip the lines you don't want, and print only the lines you do want - with the correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the complete file to a buffer and apply a regex:

```
my $buffer = "";
while(<>) {
    $buffer .= $_;
}

$buffer =~ s|<P>\s+<P>\s(.*?)\n|<p>\n$1\n</p>\n|gs;

print "$buffer\n";
```